# route-to-component accessing wired ui-view bindings in resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router with a component architecture. In my template I have something like `<div ui-view projectId="$ctrl.projectId"></div>`.

How can I access the `projectId` binding from within a resolve? The following will throw an error as no provider is found for `projectId`.

```
{
  state: 'test',
  resolve: {
    test: (projectId, MyService) => MyService.get(projectId),
  },
  component: 'MyComponent',
}
```

Comment: Insetad of asking "I want to do this", your chances of getting good answers will be more if you specify the reason behind doing this.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the `projectId` in the root container and pass it down to other components. Otherwise I need to place it in a service, and it seems funny to have to update the service.projectId whenever the root container projectId is updated.

Comment: This sounds like the job for a state parameter, possibly in the URL.

Comment: @ChrisT do you have an example of how I could do that? In my actual code, I need to pass on object, not an id, so the url is out. Is the only way to pass state params using `$state.go` or can they be inherited? I would need to be able to set the state param from the root component (contains the `ui-view` for all child states), and want it to be accessible via all child components.

Comment: See the sample app https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs/blob/fd30352892c8c3646ccb78c1a8f9a0dddc49230a/app/mymessages/mymessages.states.js#L33-L40 for common examples.   In this case, folderId is a string.  You can use full objects as parameters too by declaring them in the `params` block (not in the url), but this isn't usually a good idea.  The way you describe your problem leads me to believe there are better approaches.  Managing data "from the root component" and "pass an object" (the projectId?) doesn't seem like the best approach.